# Hide suggested text when typing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Does anyone know how to turn off this annoying popup in Visual Studio Community 2019?

All the answers I see for it are for Visual Studio Code when I google it, which says to change it under the "File" > "Preferences" menu. Visual Studio 2019 doesn't have that menu. I just want to code without visual obstructions from my editor. Driving me nuts. Thank you!

The language is VB in ASP Classic environment.

[image]

I have turned off everything I could find that seems like it could be related to a popup under the "Options" menu, but many of the descriptions there are obscure. You could seriously make a full time job out of learning what all this stuff means.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, however odd it may be. With @JackArbiter's help in narrowing down the possibilities, it turned out to be the file type within the environment that was the issue. I didn't realize at first that it was only a certain file extension that was creating the issue. The *.asp files behaved appropriately, but the *.inc files were the problem.

I went to "Options" > "Text Editor" > "File Extension" and added the "inc" file extension there with the editor set to Visual Basic. These files now behave the same as the asp files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Tools>Options>Text Editor>[Your markup or language]** and you can adjust the intellisense settings. In your case there will be no intellisense settings listed (general HTML is what I assume to be the issue here, though you'll have to do this again probably for the language of the IF/Else code blocks) so go to HTML>General and uncheck "Auto list members" at the top.

[image]

Comment: I have "Auto list members" unchecked for all languages in the options menu, and not just under the "All Languages" option, I mean for every single one. Any other ideas?

Comment: It appears that the list is an index of keywords that already exist within the file itself...any idea what that might be called?

Comment: @ionalchemist Might be "Module Completions" include auto imports under Javascript/Typescript>Formatting? https://i.imgur.com/b3Cfdb2.png Hard to tell exactly what you're using for the code there, more info about that might be helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do it either...appreciate the suggestions though

Comment: @ionalchemist Is that inline C# or... what? Would be helpful to pin down. That'd be under C#>Intellisense then "Highlight matching portions of completion list items" https://i.imgur.com/by9icTV.png Or maybe the one beneath it? Yes, it is frustrating I know, lol. (sorry had to edit the link)

Comment: It's classic ASP using VB code. Updated the question with that info.

Comment: Also check extensions (extensions tab at top). Could be something like "Visual Studio IntelliCode" listed here on my 2019: https://i.imgur.com/X8YjRbX.png Also look at the output from intellisense if it's not an extension: https://i.imgur.com/65HKFAe.png I'm not quite used to seeing how that picture is autofilling for you so might be a 3rd party extension.

Comment: I'm seeing now that it's only happening in my include files *.inc and not in the *.asp files. The include files also don't have the rich code formatting so it perhaps thinks it's plain text.

Comment: We're totally gonna get this moved to chat but for sake of expediency... what is the output from your intellisense showing? https://i.imgur.com/ADhBRWg.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195539/discussion-between-ionalchemist-and-jackarbiter).